# How do I get a dark titlebar as seen in the iMovie application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I like to mimic the iMovie application layout. Now my guesses are that from a storyboard perspective they use a `NSWindowController` which holds a `NSSplitViewController` (Horizontally) with the top view controller being a `NSSplitViewController` (Vertically) with a `UITableView` | `UICollectionView` | And some custom view for the player. As for the bottom view controller, this would be a collection view as well.

**How do I get that dark layout in my OSX application** ?

[image]

```
window.appearance = NSAppearance.init(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
```

[image]

As you can see the titlebar is much darker then that of iMovie. Which has a more gradient lighter tone.

Comment: In the windowController, include `window.appearance = NSAppearance.init(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)`

Comment: Using that property will make the app darker but the titlebar is much to dark  compared to that of iMovie.

Comment: They create their own custom window with a borderless window for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder (or in code):
 - Set 'Transparent Title Bar' 
 - Unset 'Full Size ContentView'

[image: Interface Builder Window Appearance]

In your main window controller set the background color:

```
window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.darkGray
```

In addition you will probably have to hide the title text and add your own through an accessory view controller with `addTitlebarAccessoryViewController`.  I don't see any way of changing the title text color other than setting the appearance to dark `window?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearance.Name.vibrantDark)`

Comment: Changing the title color can be achieved by not using the real window title and adding for example an empty NSToolBar and adding a custom view in it.